# Load OpenCV image from binary string

Tags: python, opencv, wand

What I mean by binary string, is the raw content of image file (That's what [wand.image.make_blob()](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.make_blob) returns)

Is there a way to load it in OpenCV ?

### Edit:

`cv2.imdecode()` doesn't work

```
img = cv2.imdecode( buf=wand_img.make_blob(), flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

> TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert wand image object to open cv image (numpy array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015966/how-to-convert-wand-image-object-to-open-cv-image-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cv2.imdecode which takes an image buffer and turns it into a CvMat object? Though I am not sure about this one.

See : http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html