# How to convert a wand image object to numpy array (without OpenCV)?

Tags: python, numpy, pdf, wand, ndimage

I am converting pdf files to image using [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/). Then, I do further image processing using ndimage.

I would like to directly convert the Wand image into a ndarray... I have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032551/8069403), but it use OpenCV. Is this possible without using OpenCV?

For the moment I save a temporary file, which is re-opened with scipy.misc.imread()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [Wand 0.5.3](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/changes.html#version-0-5-3) this is supported directly

```py
import numpy as np
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='rose:') as img:
    array = np.array(img)
    print(array.shape)  #=> (70, 46, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a buffer, like this:

```
import cStringIO
import skimage.io
from wand.image import Image
import numpy

#create the image, then place it in a buffer
with Image(width = 500, height = 100) as image:
    image.format        = 'bmp'
    image.alpha_channel = False
    img_buffer=numpy.asarray(bytearray(image.make_blob()), dtype=numpy.uint8)

#load the buffer into an array
img_stringIO = cStringIO.StringIO(img_buffer)
img = skimage.io.imread(img_stringIO)

img.shape
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python3 version of [MrMartin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871701/1067132)

```py
from io import BytesIO
import skimage.io
from wand.image import Image
import numpy

with Image(width=100, height=100) as image:
    image.format = 'bmp'
    image.alpha_channel = False
    img_buffer = numpy.asarray(bytearray(image.make_blob()), dtype='uint8')
bytesio = BytesIO(img_buffer)
img = skimage.io.imread(bytesio)

print(img.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me with Python3 without buffers:

```
from wand.image import Image
import numpy
with Image(width=100, height=100) as image:
    image.format = 'gray' #If rgb image, change this to 'rgb' to get raw values
    image.alpha_channel = False
    img_array = numpy.asarray(bytearray(image.make_blob()), dtype='uint8').reshape(image.size)
```